# How to make something like Twitter for Mac top bar or GitHub's one?

Tags: cocoa, navigationbar

I'm making an app and seen that twitter has this style for navigating through views (like iOS UINavigationController):

[image: nav bar]

[image]

Is there any control that emulates that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [PXNavigationBar](http://perspx.com/work/), it features this kind of breadcrumb navigation bar.

However, about this specific type of control, I might be wrong, but I think this is part of the [Chameleon](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon) project (used by the GitHub for Mac app) and/or [TwUI](https://github.com/twitter/twui) (Twitter for Mac UI).

Comment: Did you found if it is included in Chameleon or TwUI?